# Hiding TabBar in some page in Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have this code in Xamarin Forms:

```
public partial class MainPage : TabbedPage
{
   public MainPage()
   {
      InitializeComponent();

       var playPage = new NavigationPage(new PlayPage())
       {
          Title = "Play",
          Icon = "play1.png"
       };
       var settingsPage = new NavigationPage(new SettingsPage())
       { 
          Title = "Settings",
          Icon = "settings.png"
        };
        var aboutPage = new NavigationPage(new AboutPage())
        {
           Title = "About",
           Icon = "about.png"
        };
        Children.Add(playPage);
        Children.Add(settingsPage);
        Children.Add(aboutPage);
    }
```

In `AboutPage` I have an event that open another `ContentPage` (`HelpPage`) using `Navigation.PushAsync`. Is it possible to hide the tab bar while I'm inside the `HelpPage` in `Xamarin.Forms` without hiding the navigation bar?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Xamarin forms but *Windows* Forms has open/close/load/unload events you can use to hide/show the bar - I'm assuming Xamarin forms has something similar.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do the following:

```
var page = new NavigationPage(new HelpPage());
await Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushModalAsync(page, true);
```

This will create a modal page which will cover the tab bar.

In the HelpPage, have a "Close" button or toolbar item which will call Navigation.PopModalAsync()

Comment: thanks for the reply. I forgot to mention in my post that I wanted to keep the navigation bar on top. Is this possible?

Comment: @iamsophia Do you have an image to illustrate what you mean?  I can kind of envision, but not sure completely.

Comment: I am click button to Hiding TabBar, It's possible.@Kevin Le - Khnle